# change colour of another page

Tags: javascript

Using java script is it possible to change the background color of another page, ie if i say i want the background colour to be blue, i would type it into a text box on one page, and when i click the link to the page i want the background color to be blue, its blue.
If this is possible how would i go about it???

Comment: It depends on whether it is a third party page or your a page on your own domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both pages are in (i)frames or one page is in an iframe of the other it is possible using cross-frame scripting. It is also possible if one of the pages is a popup produced by the other.

If not then it is only possible by making a whole bunch of server script and using forms and automatic refreshes or AJAX, not soemthing easily explained.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't know exactly when that other page has completed loading, if you do, then you can simply get the document.body of that other page and change the background-color style (as long as the other page is not in a different domain and the user doesn't quickly close the page where the link is).